# Speeding up std:.vector filling with new c++11 std::async

Tags: c++11, vector, stdasync

i'm using vc++ 2013 express edition.
I'm studying some new feature of c++11 like std::async, and std::future.

I have a class Foo, with an `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<unsigned int> >`.
In Foo ctor i use std::make_shared to allocate in the heap the vector;

From Foo.h

```
Class Foo{
public:
  Foo();
private:
  std::shared_ptr<std::vector<unsigned int> >  testVector;
  unsigned int MAX_ITERATIONS = 800000000;
  void fooFunction();

}
```

From Foo.cpp

```
Foo::Foo(){
testVector = std::make_shared<std::vector<unsigned int> >();
//fooFunction(); this take about 20 sec
 std::async(std::launch::async, &Foo::fooFunction, this).get(); // and this about the same!!
}


void Foo:fooFunction(){
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < MAX_ITERATIONS; i++){
    testVector->push_back(i);       
  } 

}
```

Th problem is i can't see any gain between calling std::async(std::launch::async, &Foo::fooFunction, this).get(); and fooFunction();

Why?? 
Any help will be appreciated.
Best regards

Comment: Why do you expect times to be different? Your code is effectively serialized anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[std::async](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) returns a [std::future](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future).

Calling `get()` on the future will make it wait until the result is available, then return it. So, even if it is run asynchronously, you are doing nothing but waiting for the result.

`std::async` doesn't magically parallelize the `for` loop in `Foo::fooFunction`.